# Generic issues: T extends interface type. Cannot call method to return an object which extends the type?

Tags: java, generics

I have this method declared in a parent class:

```
protected <ConfigT extends LoadableConfig> ConfigT getConfig(final String configId) {
    return (ConfigT)getConfigService().getConfig(configId, getDriver());
}
```

The configuration service method is defined as follows:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
@Override
public <ConfigT extends LoadableConfig> ConfigT getConfig(String configId, WebDriver driver) {

    //noinspection unchecked
    Map<String,LoadableConfig> profile = profiles.get(getProfileName(driver));

    if(profile != null) {
        return (ConfigT) profile.get(configId);
    }

    return null;
}
```

The configuration type I want is here:

```
public interface AccessibleConfig extends LoadableConfig, PolleableConfig {
 ....
}
```

This line of code is throwing an incompatible type error:

```
 AccessibleConfig config = getConfig(ValidationPane.class.getCanonicalName());
```

How is this possible? The `AccessibleConfig` extends `LoadableConfig`. The method called declared that that return type is some type which extends `LoadableConfig`. I am running jdk1.8.0_102.jdk. This failure happens in IntelliJ as well as when compiling with Maven from the command line. I am able to do this with other configuration types which extends the `LoadableConfig` type.

EDIT:

Parent class:

```
public abstract class AbstractLoadable<T extends AbstractLoadable<T>> {

    private Map<String,LoadableConfig> profiles = new HashMap<>();

    protected <T extends LoadableConfig> T getConfig(final String configId) {
        return (T) profiles.get(configId);
    }
}
```

Concrete class:

```
public class ConcreteLoadable extends AbstractLoadable {

    public ConcreteLoadable(final String profileName) {

        AccessibleConfig config = getConfig(ConcreteLoadable.class.getCanonicalName());
    }

}
```

And the interface types:

```
public interface LoadableConfig {
    Integer getLoadTimeoutInSeconds();
    void setLoadTimeoutInSeconds(final Integer loadTimeoutInSeconds);
}

public interface AccessibleConfig extends LoadableConfig {
    Boolean getHoverOverAccessorWithJavascript();
    void setHoverOverAccessorWithJavascript(final Boolean hoverOverAccessorWithJavascript);
    Boolean getClickAccessorWithJavascript();
    void setClickAccessorWithJavascript(final Boolean clickAccessorWithJavascript);
}
```

So, the exercise of producing this minimal example actually made it really easy to identify the source of the compiler error. I have posted an answer to this question below. I humbly accept that I did not in fact originally post a complete example.

Comment: How about a minimal, _complete_ example that shows this? There are many loose ends here.

Comment: Side note on naming: the convention is to use **single** characters for type parameters. Just call it T, not ConfigT. Anything else will confuse the hell out of any slightly experienced Java programmer.

Comment: @GhostCat It can be extended to all-uppercase names, but only in special cases with many parameters. CamelCase is the worst, definitely.

Comment: It is camel case because I was asked to do this in code reviews. I have also been criticized in the past for posting too much code and not honing in on the exact problem. So the drive by down vote is not particularly helpful.

Comment: Drive by? People have already told you what you need to do. Provide a [mcve].

Comment: I have a meeting. I will provide a more complete example when I get back.

Comment: Quick guess: try `AccessibleConfig config = <AccessibleConfig>getConfig(ValidationPane.class.getCanonicalName());`

Comment: @jjmontes Why? Do you mistrust type inference? This is such a simple case, it worked even before Java 8.

Comment: Complete example now posted. I did not include the implementations for the config classes because they are just POJOs implementing the interfaces.

Comment: But that's way too much code for the problem you have. Why don't you, for your own sake, create a _minimal_ example that reproduces your issue?

Comment: The example has been stripped down completely. Now it's only a few lines of code and reproduces the original error.

Comment: You might want to try [SOCVR](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers) for help reopening your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have identified the problem. The concrete class needs to pass itself to the parent because the parent is reflexively generic. The error message wasn't super helpful so I got tied up in thinking about the generic parameters of the parent class method and not of the generic parameters applied to the parent class itself.

The class declaration for `ConcreteLoadable` needs to changed to this to get rid of the compile error:

```
public class ConcreteLoadable extends AbstractLoadable<ConcreteLoadable> {

    public ConcreteLoadable(final String profileName) {

        AccessibleConfig config = getConfig(ConcreteLoadable.class.getCanonicalName());
    }

}
```